# Why does this make my app crash and what's the appropriate solution?

Tags: android

I have a button that I want to change its value often, so my Activity has a private variable :

```
private Button p1_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.firstbut);
```

This simple line makes my app crash. If I put inside the onCreate it works and I can interact with the button (change text etc).

EDIT : I think I found the reason. I should initialize AFTER setcontentview ?

EDIT: Thank you for the constructive answers. I have now a different problem I removed the initialization and I did it on onCreate and it works (But I keeped the p1_button declaration as a  private field). But when I tried to modify the button in a different method of my activity (just changing the text), it crashes again. So the return value of findViewById is "local" to the method where it is called and I should setcontentview in every method that access UI elements ?

Comment: For future reference: when a program crashes, _always_ give the exception and stack trace that occurs (for Android, it can be found in the logcat). "It crashes" is barely any information to work from in order to debug, whereas the exception and stack trace provide a wealth of information.

Answer (score 1):

Do not call `findViewById()` until *after* you call `setContentView()`. Otherwise, the widget will not exist.

More generally, do *not* call inherited methods on `Activity` until after `super.onCreate()`, unless specifically advised to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where you are calling this line.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EQaU.png
The onCreate() method contains a call to setContentView() and before this is called, Android has no idea what to do with your button as it hasn't been inflated yet!

Therefore as a really easy rule of thumb, always make sure setContentView (or if you're dealing with fragments onCreateView()) have been called and completed. Only then will findViewById() work.

If you would like further guidance, please post some code in which the crash occurs.

edit: I tried to add the image properly but don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 0):

To understand this you need to know the Activity lifecycle. You are trying to look a `view` which has not yet been created by Android.

As per the android lifecycle explained here "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html". In `onCreate()` method the activity is created and you can access different `view`s of the activity. If you will try to look for `view` before `onCreate()` the app will crash as it does not know whether that view exists or not.